# Webpack - error - Must export a default export when using ES6 modules

Tags: webpack

I'm working with React. When launching my webpack build, my console returns:

> ERROR in ./src/index.js
>
> ```
> Module build failed (from ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>
> Error: Must export a default export when using ES6 modules.
> ```

Here my .babelrc file :

```
{
  "presets": ["module:@babel/core", "@babel/preset-env" ,"@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Here the file snippet:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import Editor from "./Editor"


if (module.hot){module.hot.accept()} ;


ReactDOM.render(
    <Editor/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

I can't figure out what is wrong, it is the first time I see this error. Also the documentation available on the web is very abstractive. I have found only 7 Google results with my key phrase quoted. Please help.

Comment: post your babel.config.js or .babelrc or babel-loader options so we can analyse a little more.

Comment: I have edited my topic

Comment: seems having settings my babelrc as folllowing `"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]` seems to work better, I'm now struggling with webpack and scoped package, apparently webpack require some additionals configuration to work with scoped packages

Answer (score 0):

In presets in your .babelrc file, remove

> "module:@babel/core"

In your webpack configuration, add

```
{
   target: "node"
}.
```

Your Es 6 import will start working in your express file, but you need to enter each file using its extension. For example.

```
import App from "./src/app.js"
```